# Print PDF and Send to Contact

Tags: civimail, message-templates, pdf

We currently use CiviEvent extensively for online courses. When a person completes a course, we're able to use our certificate template to print out tokenized PDFs and then send those to the participants via other mailing means (Outlook, etc.). Is there a way to simultaneously print said PDF and send it via an attachment to the participant through CiviMail to cut down on staff time?

Comment: I thought for a moment that Search, then the Actions = Print/Merge Document was what you want, but i see you are saying "and sends as attachment". Hmm. Receipts let you 'attach PDF", but Actions, and Scheduled Reminders don't afaik. Have you searched for Extensions?

Comment: I think you could using a few components such as CiviRules and perhaps some custom tokens to get the right file attached. An alternative might be to get CiviCRM to send them a link to download the PDF themselves - might be easier to manage and easier to automate?

Comment: I'm looking for a very similar solution. Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yes this would be a good feature.

Comment: @ParvezSaleh 5 years later... can we do this? How would you generate that link that (creates and) lets them download their PDF? Also wonder if https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/pdfapi/-/tree/master/ is part of a solution